# Set EntityImage Using JavaScript Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I need to add an image that is already in web resources (jpg)
and according to the name of the product in my entity the entityimage is filled.

I'm using the following Script but it's not working; the result that is returning is empty, causing an error.

The event is triggered on change of the product name field and is calling the function `SetImage()`.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

```js
//Hook this method to the "OnChange" event of "creditlimit" field
     function SetImage() 
     {
 debugger;
    var productId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    var productName = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").getValue();
 
    if (productName != null) 
    {
 
        //retrieve image onecoinpile.jpg and update product record "EntityImage" attribute
        this.UpdateproductRecordWithNewImage(productId, "new_BurgerGift.jpg");
 
    }
}

 function UpdateproductRecordWithNewImage(productId, webResourceName)
 {

 debugger;
    this.GetImageWebResource
    (
        productId,
        webResourceName,
        this.UpdateProductRecord
    );
 
}



function GetImageWebResource(productId, imageName, successCallback) 
{
   debugger;
 
    //OData URI to get address information from parent account record
    var oDataURI = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()
        + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/"
        + "WebResourceSet"
        + "?$filter="
        + "Name eq '" + imageName + "'"
        + "&$select=Name,Content";


    //Synchronous XMLHttpRequest to retrieve account record
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", encodeURI(oDataURI), false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        debugger;
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) 
        {
            req.onreadystatechange = null; //avoids memory leaks
            if (this.status == 200) 
            {
                //parse the response string as a JSON object into the successCallback method.
                successCallback(productId, JSON.parse(this.responseText).d);
            }
            else 
            {
               alert("error");
                var errorMsg1 = "GetImageWebResource Error: cannot retrieve image with name = " + imageName + ".";
                //display a non-blocking alert dialog
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(errorMsg1, function () { });
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}


 function UpdateProductRecord(recordId, webResource) 
 {
   debugger;
 

 try{
    //var product = {EntityImage:""};
    var product = webResource.results[0].Content; //byte[] content of the web resource
    
    alert(product);
   
    var jsonproduct= JSON.stringify(product);
    alert(jsonproduct);
   }catch(ex){
      console.log(ex);
   }
 
    //OData URI
    var oDataURI = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl()
        + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/"
        + "productSet(guid'" + recordId + "')";
    alert(oDataURI);
    //Synchronous post
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", encodeURI(oDataURI), false);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () 
    {
        debugger;
        if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) 
        {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status == 204 || this.status == 1223) 
            {
                //reloads the product record
                window.location.reload(false);
            }
            else 
            {
               alert("error");
                var errorMsg2 = "UpdateProductRecord Error: Cannot update product record with productId = " + recordId + ".";
                //display a non-blocking alert dialog
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(errorMsg2, function () { });
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(jsonproduct);
    alert(jsonproduct);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the jpg file webresource into product entity record?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the image that is stored in web resources into product entity

Comment: You didn’t mention the “entityimage” attribute to update ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, it should be working when you change the below lines.

```
var product = {};
product.EntityImage = webResource.results[0].Content;
```

You mentioned, result is empty. Can you verify by placing small case `new_burgergift.jpg` instead of `new_BurgerGift.jpg`.

Always check before accessing child elements like:

```
if(webResource.results[0])
    product.EntityImage = webResource.results[0].Content;
```